# What is the role of RCTSRWebSocket in iOS version React Native?

Tags: ios, websocket, react-native

I saw 'RCTSRWebSocket' in iOS version React Native project, but I can't find any 'import' of this lib in whole project. so what's the role of RCTSRWebSocket in React Native? I guess it's be used to connect Terminal and Simulator?

Answer (score 0):

It's one of the fundamental native modules of React Native.
It's used for dual simultaneous communication, at least, with the bundler service.

Android also has this module (Java implementation) for the same purpose.